# Horizontal listview one below the other android

Tags: android, horizontallistview

I want to create 2 horizontal listview one below the other. I dont want the listview to scroll seperatley, when the user swipes the screen both the lists should get scrolled .

I created 2 horizontal listview as in this project ,
https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

but both the listview can be scrolled separately. Can anyone help me create it.

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

- Define you own [RecyclerView.OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html) class.
- For each RecyclerView, add your scroll listener using [addOnScrollListener (RecyclerView.OnScrollListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener))
- In your Ativity/Fragment, listen to your scroll listener onScrolled method using the observer pattern.
- When one Recycler view scrolls, you Activity/Framgent iterate your Recycler views and scroll them using [scrollTo(int x,int y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener)) method.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
if( this.getScrollY() != otherList.getScrollY() )
    otherList.setScrollY( this.getScrollY() );
```

In the onScroll method of the onScrollListener. The above is pretty rough.

If this is suitable to you then please mark as accepted answer so that it could be helpful for others.